# VSCode Python debugger throwing ImportError ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm running tests for my project which contains several modules:

```
├── compute_metrics_service
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── integration
        │   ├── test_app.py
        │   └── __init__.py
│   │   └── unit
│   └── utils
├── data_quality
│   ├── helpers
│   └── tests
│       ├── integration
│       └── unit
└── fetch_data_metrics
    ├── helpers
    └── tests
        ├── integration
        └── unit
```

For example, I'm trying to debug a test inside of `compute_metrics_service/tests/integration` with VSCode, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError: 'test_app' module incorrectly imported from '/Users/xxxx/Documents/SOC/data-quality-tool/data_quality/tests/integration'. Expected '/Users/xxxx/Documents/SOC/data-quality-tool/compute_metrics_service/tests/integration'. Is this module globally installed?
```

I've set my PYTHONPATH the following way:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH="$PWD/data_quality:$PWD/compute_metrics_service:$PWD/fetch_data_metrics"
```

`test_app.py` is simply a TestCase, similar to the following:

```py
import unittest
import os
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch, mock_open
from compute_metrics_service import app
from compute_metrics_service.utils import Helpers


class TestMainCompleteness(unittest.TestCase):
 ...
```

What am I missing?

TIA!

Comment: What's `test_app`? Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem

Comment: Sure @MingJie-MSFT, I've just added more context.